# Can I use Grunt with TFS?

Tags: javascript, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, gruntjs

My new project needs me to work with TFS + Git.

Confession: I know nothing about TFS.

I want to setup a build for my JavaScript project. I want to use Grunt.

Is this possible? Has anybody used Grunt with TFS?

Comment: Did you see this https://github.com/danactive/grunt-tfs-unlock?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On our current project, we're using Grunt and TFS. I've integrated Grunt with TFS by caling it from a bat file which you can hook up in the [Pre- or Post-BuildEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) section of your project file.

However, because TFS will execute your builds with specific environment variables, you need to use absolute paths.

**A list of the things we've done**

1. Install node.js on your build machine (as well as on your development machine(s) ofcourse)
2. Add a `package.json`file on the root of your JavaScript project.
3. Use `npm` to install `grunt-cli` **locally** (!). Use the `--save-dev` flag to add this package to the development dependencies section in `package.json`
4. For all other packages you need, use npm with the same flag as in step 3
5. Write a bat file (see example below) in which you'll

   1. make use of absolute paths
   2. use npm to install all the packages listed in the packages.json file
   3. call grunt
6. In your Pre- or PostBuildEvents, call this bat file

**bat file example**

```
rem use call to execute other bat files
echo npm install 
call "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm" install

rem because we have listed grunt-cli as a dev dependency,
rem the executable will be located in the node_modules folder
echo grunt
call "./node_modules/.bin/grunt"
```

Comment: I'd love to know more information from the perspective of someone that is already familiar with using TFS and would like to start using grunt and isn't familiar with it yet.  Also are there no nuget packages for this?  Seems like you could easily put a lot of this in a nuget package.

Comment: @AllenRice IMO the only thing you could put in a npm here is either nodejs or grunt. All the other packages are npm packages. Unfortunately, I haven't found nuget packages for grunt and there aren't any popular ones out there for nodejs. You could try this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/nji/ which would make only step 1 obsolete.

Comment: Why should I install ```grunt-cli``` locally?

Comment: @MatthiasDailey I did it to avoid PATH issues. When you install `grunt-cli` locally you can locate it locally under the npm_modules

Answer (score 2):

I use grunt with TFS when I have to use TFS. I've tried grunt-tfs-unlock, but ran into this [issue](https://github.com/danactive/grunt-tfs-unlock/issues/2). I solved the problem using grunt-shell, which works and leaves you more in charge of the configuration. This [gist](https://gist.github.com/localnerve/6112944) shows how I use TFS with grunt. It demonstrates the 'tf checkout' command, but you could easily create any tf command with this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the answers listed here and wasn't able to get a successful automated build and deploy with TFS until I used [NCapsulate](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=ncapsulate). It removes the need for NodeJs to be installed separately on build agents or dev machines. Just a NuGet package.

Just make sure you set up your build targets properly and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a full example scenario on how to use grunt on the build server:
http://www.codit.eu/blog/2015/03/18/continuous-integration-with-javascript-nunit-on-tfsbuild-(part-23)/

Answer (score 0):

After installing node etc... on your build server, you could also modify your build template and add a step to call grunt etc.... This would prevent you from having to modify your csproj file and allow you to use the environmental variables created by TFS instead.