# MVC + Angular + Twitter Bootstrap Compile and Minify

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, azure, less

My app is using ASP.NET MVC, Angular, and Twitter Bootstrap. As you can imagine, there are lots of JS and LESS files. The app is hosted on Windows Azure and being built on TFS. I'm looking for a recommendation on the best LESS compiler, CSS minifier, JS minifier solution. The caveat is I want the compile/minify to only happen on publish to Azure, as part of the build process. For local dev, I wish the browser to do compile less using the less.js library, javascript is as written. I also do not want to require a build in Visual Studio locally every time a little change is made to less or js files.

Previously I was using ReduceRequest which does everything on the server-side based upon a web.config setting. However, ReduceRequest relies on DotLess which is no longer in active development (does not support less 1.4.x and higher).

Cassette and BundleTransformer, as well as MVC bundles appear to require a build to capture any file changes.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**Edit**

To clarify, I am using the "hosted build controller" that is part of TFS so any solution would need to take this into account: http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/hosted-build-controller-in-vs#software

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and its various modules.  You can do all of those things that you want and you can set up different configurations for different environments (dev, prod etc)

Comment: The app is being built using TFS. Node isn't an option.

Comment: Ah I didn't know it restricted you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399116/can-i-use-grunt-with-tfs suggests it's doable but not straight forward.  I'm not familiar with a a ms stack alternative, sorry

Comment: Good link, thanks. It talks about using TFS as the source control repository and building using a node.js with Grunt build box essentially. In this case, I'm building using the hosted build capabilities of TFS. http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/hosted-build-controller-in-vs#software. I've updated the question to call this out.