# Is it possible to take latest from TFS using grunt?

Tags: node.js, tfs, gruntjs

Is it possible to take latest from TFS using grunt ?  i have used grunt-tfs-unlock but it did not work at all !

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/a/18084495/1225429?

Answer (score 0):

All plugins for Grunt listed here: http://gruntjs.com/plugins . And only the tfs-unlock plugin works for integrated Grunt with TFS.

However, only Checkout and undo are currently supported in "tfs-unlock" task, you can't get latest from TFS with it. Check:https://github.com/danactive/grunt-tfs-unlock